# Haskell parsing tools - yacc:lex :: happy:?

Tags: haskell, yacc, parsing, lex

So, it seems like [Happy](http://www.haskell.org/happy) is a robust replacement for yacc in Haskell.  Is there an equally robust lexer generator to replace lex/flex?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Alex? http://www.haskell.org/alex/

> a tool for generating lexical analysers in Haskell, given a description of the tokens to be recognised in the form of regular expressions. It is similar to the tool lex or flex for C/C++...
>
> Alex is part of the [Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_Platform), so if you install the platform you will automatically have a working Alex.
>
> Alex is also on Hackage. If you have the [cabal-install](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/hackage/wiki/CabalInstall) tool (which also comes with the Haskell Platform), then you can build and install the latest version of Alex with
>
> ```
>     cabal install alex
> ```
>
> To find out what the latest version of Alex is, and to download the source separately, go to Alex's [HackageDB page](http://hackage.haskell.org/cgi-bin/hackage-scripts/package/alex).
>
> Alex might also be pre-packaged for your OS...

Answer (score 5):

Happy : Yacc :: Alex : Lex

Or use one of a gazillion parser and lexer combinator libraries.